# Дистрибуция приложения, зависящего от библиотеки, не присутствующей в репозиториях

Tags: windows, c++, qt, библиотеки, linux

Мое приложение зависит от библиотеки, которая существует только в виде исходников. Она имеет лицензию LGPL, поэтому я не могу статически прилинковать ее к приложению. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы она лежала в папке с приложением и бралась оттуда? Как это сделать? Приложение и библиотека на Qt и собираются в Linux и Windows.

Я спрашиваю о том, как сказать приложению, что библиотеку надо искать не в /usr/bin, а в папке с бинарником?

Comment: @Robotex, хороший вопрос. Мне понравился. Пока почитайте [вот это](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html).

Если сами не придумаете, как через LD_LIBRARY_PATH (для \*nix) сделать, то в воскресенье вечером или в понедельник подкину чего-нибудь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[@Robotex](/users/8635/robotex)](/users/8635/robotex), на Ваш вопрос

```
Т.е. я не имею права скомпилить библиотеку в .so и положить внутрь пакета с моим приложением?
```

я бы ответил отрицательно. Действительно, самыми простыми способами будет:

1. установить .so (например в /usr/local/bin), прописать ее в /etc/ld.so.conf.d  и запустить ldconfig  (или перезагрузить комп)
2. прописать в LD_LIBRARY_PATH путь к библиотеке (в составе приложения) где-нибудь в ~/.bashrc
3. запускать приложение через shell скрипт, в котором прописать в LD_LIBRARY_PATH путь к библиотеке

Но, все эти способы требуют некоторых действий по **установке** приложения, а иногда хочется что-то вроде

```
tar xvf my-progs.tar
export PATH=$PATH:/tram-pam-pam/my-progs
```

и

```
my-bestprog arg1 arg2
```

Такую штуку можно сделать, написав некую "обертку" к программе, использующей .so, если известно взаимное (относительное) расположение "обертки", программы и оглавления с .so
"Обертка" будет вычислять абсолютный путь, откуда ее запустили (в смысле где она лежит), добавлять к environment LD_LIBRARY_PATH путь к библиотеке и запускать основную программу.

Например это можно реализовать так:

```
// txaxa.c  программа вызывающая функцию xaxa() из shared library
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < ac; i++)
    printf ("av[%d] = [%s]\n",i,av[i]);

  xaxa("xa-xa");

  exit(0);
}
```

А это функция в shared library

```
// xaxa.c эта функция помещается в shared library libxaxa.so
#include <stdio.h>

void
xaxa (char *txt)
{
  printf ("shared lib xaxa(): %s\n",txt);
}
```

Соберем приложение xaxa

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode/tst$ gcc -fPIC -shared xaxa.c -o libxaxa.so
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode/tst$ gcc -o xaxa txaxa.c -L. -lxaxa
```

Добавим "обертку"

```
// rxaxa.c добавляет к LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./lib, где  в ./lib/libxaxa.so лежит xaxa()
// и вызывает "приложение" xaxa (txaxa.c) 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  fprintf (stderr,"%s\n", 
       exewithlibso ("./xaxa","lib",av)? 
       "Can't find path to executable": "execvp error\n");
  exit (1);
}
```

И соберем в каталоге .prog наше приложение

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode/tst$ gcc  rxaxa.c guessfrom.c -o rxaxa
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode/tst$ mkdir prog
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode/tst$ mkdir prog/lib
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode/tst$ cp libxaxa.so prog/lib/
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode/tst$ cp xaxa rxaxa prog/
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode/tst$ tar cvf my-prog.tar ./prog/
./prog/
./prog/lib/
./prog/lib/libxaxa.so
./prog/xaxa
./prog/rxaxa
```

Теперь распакуем .tar куда-нибудь и можно вызывать (все работает)

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode/tst$ cd /tmp
avp@avp-ubu1:/tmp$ tar xf /home/avp/hashcode/tst/my-prog.tar 
avp@avp-ubu1:/tmp$ ./prog/rxaxa call xaxa
av[0] = [./prog/rxaxa]
av[1] = [call]
av[2] = [xaxa]
shared lib xaxa(): xa-xa
avp@avp-ubu1:/tmp$ PATH=$PATH:/tmp/prog/
avp@avp-ubu1:/tmp$ cd 
avp@avp-ubu1:~$ pwd
/home/avp
avp@avp-ubu1:~$ rxaxa call xaxa and it works
av[0] = [rxaxa]
av[1] = [call]
av[2] = [xaxa]
av[3] = [and]
av[4] = [it]
av[5] = [works]
shared lib xaxa(): xa-xa
avp@avp-ubu1:~$
```

А вот функции, которые делают эту штуку

```
// avp 2012

#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <errno.h>
#include  <sys/stat.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include  <sys/param.h>
#include  <unistd.h>

/*
  Разбивает путь к файлу (pname) на имя файла и каталоги
  Каталаги возвращаются в path
  Имя файла в name
 */
static void
splitpathname(char *pname, char *path, char *name)
{
  char *p = pname+strlen(pname)-1;

  *path = *name = 0;
  while ((p >= pname) && (*p != '/')) p--;
  strcpy(name,p+1);
  if (p > pname)
    strncat(path,pname,p-pname);
}

/*
  Проверяет можно ли выполнить (exec) путь av0
  Если да, возвращает 1 
      и кладет в pfrom absolute path к программе, а по адресу exe (если не NULL)
      последний компонент из av0 (имя программы)
  иначе возвращает 0
 */
static int 
checkexe  (char *av0, char *pfrom, char *exe)
{
  struct stat st;

  if (stat(av0,&st) == 0 && (st.st_mode & S_IFREG) && access(av0,X_OK) == 0) {
    char name[PATH_MAX], path[PATH_MAX];

    splitpathname(av0,path,name);
    if (path[0]) {
      char  curwd[PATH_MAX];
      getcwd(curwd,PATH_MAX);
      chdir(path);
      getcwd(pfrom,PATH_MAX);
      chdir(curwd);
    } else {
      strcpy(pfrom,".");
    }
    if (exe)
      strcpy(exe,name);
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

static int
getpathpart (char **pb, char *p)
{  
  if (!*pb)
    return 0;
  char *t = *pb;
  int  l = 0;

  while (*t && *t == ':')
    t++;
  if (*t)
    *pb = t;
  while (*t && *t != ':')
    p[l++] = *t++;
  p[l] = 0;
  return l;
}

/*
  Функция определяет абсолютный путь к запущенной программе
  по значению argv[0] с учетом envirinment PATH

  Returns
    1  OK
    0  установить путь не удалось
  В случае успеха возвращает в pfrom найденный путь (без имени программы),
  а в exe имя программы
 */
int
guessfrom (char *av0, char *pfrom, char *exe)
{
  if (!av0 || *av0 == 0)
    return 0;

  if (checkexe(av0, pfrom, exe))
    return 1;
  int  l;
  char *beg, pexe[PATH_MAX];

  for (beg = getenv("PATH"); l = getpathpart(&beg,pexe); beg += l) {
    pexe[l] = '/';
    strcpy(pexe+l+1,av0);
    //    printf ("pexe: [%s]\n",pexe);

    if (checkexe(pexe,pfrom,exe))
      return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}

/*
  Добавляет компонент в начало environment переменной типа LD_LIBRARY_PATH,
  PATH  и т.п.
 */
void
addtopath (char *pathname, char *elem)
{
  char *p = getenv(pathname), *t;
  int  l = strlen(elem);
  if (p && (t = strstr(p,elem))) {
    if (t[l] == 0 || t[l] == ':')
      return;
  }

  char newpath[l+1+ (p? strlen(p): 0)];

  strcpy(newpath,elem);
  if (p) {
    newpath[l] = ':';
    strcpy(newpath+l+1,p);
  }
  setenv (pathname,elem,1);
}

/*
  Запускает программу, добавляя компонент к LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  prog   - относительный путь к программе
  libdir - относительный путь к оглавлению с .so, добавляемому к LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  av     - аргументы (включая argv[0]) запускаемой программы
  Returns
      0  - не удалось выполнить execvp
      -1 - не удалось определить путь к программе
 */
int
exewithlibso (char *prog, char *libdir, char **av)
{
  char path[PATH_MAX];

  if (guessfrom(av[0], path, 0)) {
    //    printf ("I am from: [%s]\n",path);
    int l = strlen(path);
    path[l] = '/';
    strcpy(path+l+1,libdir);
    addtopath("LD_LIBRARY_PATH",path);
    //    printf ("ld_path: [%s]\n",path);
    path[l] = '/';
    strcpy(path+l+1,prog);
    execvp(path,av);
    return 0;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Вроде работает.

Собственно, подобная идея (правда в плане чтения конфигурационных файлов) о "сомонастраивающихся" программах была у меня давно, а вот заинтересовался Вашим вопросом и реализовал для .so

Если понравилось, пользуйтесь.

Answer (score 4):

[`(IANAL)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL)

- Если вы распространяете приложение, которое линкуется с библиотекой под `LGPL`, то вы должны предоставить способ пересобрать свое приложение с новой версией используемой библиотеки.
- В случае статической линковки с этой библиотекой, лично я не знаю такого способа, кроме распространения исходного кода. Наверно, можно распространять только соответствующие `obj` файлы, но вроде это не практикуется.
- Почему у вас отпал вариант собрать обсуждаемую `LGPL` библиотеку как `.dll / .so` и использовать динамическую линковку?

Comment: Вот как раз я и хочу собрать библиотеку как .dll / .so но как ее подгружать из папки с программой. Можно где-то об этом почитать?

Comment: @Robotex

- На `Windows` системе все очевидно, а под `Linux,` вам, видимо, нужно будет собрать правильный `package`, который будет предполагать, что такая `.so` уже установлена на машине пользователя.

- Если нет - то должен быть `package,` который установит эту библиотеку и, соответственно, вы просто на него сошлетесь в вашем `packag'e.` Если для выбранной вами системы такого `package` еще нет, то вам придется самостоятельно `maintain'ить` его.

- Нельзя просто взять и распространить свое приложение вместе с некоторой `.so,` поскольку это противоречит организации `shared libraries` на `*nix`

Comment: Т.е. я не имею права скомпилить библиотеку в .so и положить внутрь пакета с моим приложением?
А возможно собрать ее в .deb, положить внутрь моего .deb пакета и устанавливать после установки моего приложения?